# How to represent "options" for my plugin architecture (C# .NET WinForms)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, controls

Okay basically here's where I'm at.

I have a list of [PropertyDescriptor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.propertydescriptor.aspx) objects.  These describe the custom "Options" fields on my Plugins, aka:

```
public class MyPlugin : PluginAbstract, IPlugin
{
 [PluginOption("This controls the color of blah blah blah")]
 [DefaultValue(Color.Red)]
 public Color TheColor { get; set; }

 [PluginOption("The number of blah blah blahs")]
 [DefaultValue(10)]
 public int BlahBlahBlahs { get; set; }
}
```

So I did all the hard parts: I have all the descriptions, default values, names and types of these custom "plugin options".

MY QUESTION IS:  When a user loads a plugin, how should I represent these options for them to config?  On the back end I'll be using XML for the config, so that's not what I'm asking.  I'm asking on the front end: **What kind of WinForms control should I use to let users configure the options of a plugin, when there will be an unknown amount of options and different types used etc.?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've always used the standard built-in Winforms [PropertyGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.propertygrid.aspx).  It works well for different types of properties and for varying numbers as well.

Comment: This definitely looks promising.  Thanks for responding.

Comment: Thanks pretty much exactly what I was looking for.  I'd vote you up by I need more rep haha

Comment: While I think the PropertyGrid is the only out-of-the-box control thay will fit your needs, IMHO it's not a very user-friendly control. Any time I see an app that uses this control, I cringe. That said, you need to consider your audience.